# Combine map points - Google map API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a javascript Google Map that starts with a full world view and has a lot of clustered points in certain areas. Because the points on the map are so close it just looks like a lot of overlapping pins and makes it impossible to click on any of them accepted the top pin. What I'd like to do is combine all of the clustered points into one point that could be clicked for a list of all of the combined locations when viewing the whole map or a large section of it and spread the points back out when zoomed into that area of the map. I've had a good look around and can't seem to find any way to do it, am I missing something or is there a workaround that would allow this?

Thanks for all of your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a really good write-up of various options here:  http://www.svennerberg.com/2009/01/handling-large-amounts-of-markers-in-google-maps/

It includes MarkerManager, Clusterer, ClusterMarkup, and MarkerClusterer.

Answer (score 2):

I use Clusterer and have been happy with it. Fairly simple and straight forward

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/examples.html

Here is another option that I found afterwards that may be worth a look into as well

http://gmap3.net/examples/clustering.html

**Update:**

More recent Google documentation, some good information!

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers